# Checking which radio buttons are not checked in angular2/ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

Am building an application and i would like to check which radio buttons are not checked in a form

This is my code

```
<form [formGroup]="inspectionform" style="padding: 20px">

<ion-card *ngFor='let checklists of inspectionform.controls["inputfileds"]["controls"] ;let i=index'>

 <ion-row radio-group (ionChange)="onChange($event)">
     <ion-col width-30>
       <ion-item>
           <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
           <ion-radio id={{i}}  value='{{checklists.controls["radiovalue"].value}}-yes'  ></ion-radio>
       </ion-item>
     </ion-col>


     <ion-col width-30 style="text-align:right; margin:auto">

         <ion-item  style="text-align:left">
             <ion-label>No</ion-label>
              <ion-radio id={{i}} value='{{checklists.controls["radiovalue"].value}}-no'></ion-radio>

       </ion-item>

     </ion-col>

 </ion-row>
```

```
</form>
```

Then i have a form builder code as

```
let inspectionform: FormGroup;
      let checkinputs: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
      for (let i = 0; i < this.checklists.length; i++) {
        checkinputs.push(
          new FormGroup({
            description:new FormControl(this.checklists[i].item),
            input: new FormControl(''),
            radiovalue: new FormControl(this.checklists[i].id),

          })
        )
      }

      this.inspectionform = this._formBuilder.group({
        inputfileds: this._formBuilder.array(checkinputs.controls)
      })
```

Now on the submit on the form i would like to check the radio buttons which are not checked but i havent found a way yet. How do i go about it

So something like

```
onSubmit(){
  console.log("these radio buttons with id's are not checked")
 }
```

The id of the radio buttons is the value of index

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new property "isSelected" to your "checklists" object.
Then bind this object to your view.

```
<ion-item>
         <ion-label>No</ion-label>
         <ion-radio id={{i}} [checked]='checklists.controls.isSelected' value='{{checklists.controls["radiovalue"].value}}-no'></ion-radio>

</ion-item>
```

And then, you have just to manipulate your object to know which object is selected or not.

It's better to get a ViewModel layer to manipulate your data instead of manipulating your view directly.